# rails - how to refer to model through string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for example

```
str_modelname="User"
```

and i'd like to do

```
str_modelname.find(:first)
```

to find first User, but it doesn't work this way of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str_modelname.classify.constantize.find(:first)
```

Comment: While this solution is prettier than the one I provided, I still advocate mine, as it lets you limit the set of classes for which you can use it. Also, notice that you aren't checking for NameError and NoMethodError in case of wrong input.

Comment: However this does answer the question.  It is then up to the deeveloper to apply any guards required by the application.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways, one of which may be using an hash, like:

```
models = {"User" => User, "AnotherModel" => AnotherModel}
```

And then:

```
models[name] ? models[name].find(:first) : nil
```

Why do you need this? There could be better solutions, depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having success with this snippet of code, but I won't claim that it's the best way:

```
str = "User"
p Kernel.const_get(str).find(:first)
```

I based this off of [this technique](http://infovore.org/archives/2006/08/02/getting-a-class-object-in-ruby-from-a-string-containing-that-classes-name/).

Comment: the question is, where the string comes from? if it's from the user, this can be unsafe...

Comment: It seems like that's a problem inherent to the question rather than this particular solution.